# why package.json script works fine on local project but doesn't work on a dependency project

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

I have created a npm module(let call it `ModuleA`) and defined `clean` script in its package.json file like below:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "nyc mocha tests/ --opts mocha.opts",
    "build": "babel -d dist/ src/",
    "prepublish": "yarn run clean && yarn run build",
    "postinstall": "yarn run clean && yarn run build",
    "clean": "rimraf ./dist"
  },
```

I use `rimraf` to remove the `dist` directory. This dependency is defined in `devDependencies` as `"rimraf": "^2.6.1"`. It works fine on this project. But in one of my other project (let call it `ModuleB`) which has a dependency on this module, the `yarn install` doesn't work and I get below error:

```
$ rimraf ./dist
sh: 1: rimraf: not found
```

this error happens when `npm/yarn` is building the `ModuleB`. I have checked that `rimraf` exist in `node_modules/.bin` directory in `ModuleB`. It works fine if I install `rimraf` globally. I wonder how I can make the npm/yarn to use `rimraf` from `node_modules/.bin/rimraf`?

BTW, I also put the `rimraf` in `devDependencies` in `ModuleB`.

I tried to update the script in `ModuleA` to use `rimraf` from `node_modules/.bin/rimraf` as below:

```
"clean": "node_modules/.bin/rimraf ./dist"
```

it works fine on `ModuleA`. But I got below error when run `yarn install` on `ModuleB`:

```
$ node_modules/.bin/rimraf ./dist 
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
sh: node_modules/.bin/rimraf: No such file or directory
error Command failed with exit code 127.
```

Comment: Are you using `yarn` or `npm` ?

Comment: `"clean": "node_modules/.bin/rimraf ./dist"` ?

Comment: I tried both `yarn` and `npm`.

Comment: @AlexBlex use `node_modules/.bin/rimraf ./dist` should work but I don't understand why `yarn install` works fine on building the module. But it doesn't work when building a module which has the dependency.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to put the actual question in the title then? You see, people answer the question you put in the title - "how to use the binary", not "why it works there and doesn't work there"

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have updated the title.

Comment: @AlexBlex acutally I just tried `node_modules/.bin/rimraf ./dist` doesn't work as well. I have posted the error.

Comment: Sorry, but "this error happens when npm is building the ModuleA" and "it works fine on ModuleA" 10 lines later is quite hard to comprehend. Is there a way to prepare a minimal package.json for both modules to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Sorry it is a typo. I have corrected. It should be `this error happens when npm is building the ModuleB`

Comment: Fair enough, so to summarise: ModuleB has rimraf as devDependency. You run `npm install` and confirm `node_modules/.bin/rimraf` exist. Then you run `npm run clean` and get the error. Is it about right?

Comment: Actually I got the error when run `yarn install` on `ModuleB`.

Answer (score 0):

See those issues:

- https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/721 (postinstall hook doesn't appear to be run #721)
- https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/853 (preinstall and postinstall are not run #853)
- https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/614 (Bug: issue with postinstall scripts in git-hooks package)

Now make sure that `yarn clean` **and** `npm clean` works as expected.

For example this will not work if you didn't install `rimraf` globally:

```
$ rimraf ./dist
```

But this should work:

```
$ ./node_modules/.bin/rimraf ./dist
```

Test those commands first:

```
npm run clean
```

and:

```
yarn run clean
```

to use the `"clean": "rimraf ./dist"` script defined in package.json.

Note that `./node_modules/.bin` is added to your `PATH` when you run package.json scripts.

Try running the commands from the simple ones where you run the script directly without `npm` or `yarn`, then test with both `npm`and `yarn`, and then finally try to narrow down the problem with postinstall hooks.

Comment: In my `ModuleA` package.json, I have defined `yarn run clean && yarn run build` for `postinstall` and `postinstall`. Why doesn't it use the script defined in `package.json`?